# Trying to boot Ubuntu for first time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-drive

I'm wanting to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 11. I have Ubuntu on a flash drive and have been waiting about 40 minutes for it to boot. It's on the initial boot screen where it just says "HP" on the middle of the screen and "Ubuntu" at the bottom of the screen while the "loading circle" is spinning. How long do I wait before I just have to accept that it's not working and try something else? Is there something I can do? Is it normal to take this long?

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details, so we can only guess. You also gave no clues as to your hardware, again so we're rather limited. Normally a system takes on a seconds to a minute to boot from *live* media on flash drive, but there are boxes with firmware issues that can take 10-30 minutes due to non-compliant firmware bugs which impact some releases of Ubuntu (& *flavor*) Desktop ISOs, but you gave no details. Did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? and write of ISO to media?  (using procedures that match your *unstated* product)

Comment: Your issue may also be *graphics* driver related (*you gave no hardware details*) so a `nomodeset` or simpler graphics option at boot is required; but you gave no Ubuntu product details so we cannot know if this is an issue either.  Please provide clear details (Ubuntu product/release details & of your hardware inc. graphics).

Comment: HP Envy AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics 2.30 GHz  trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS thank you for responding

Comment: i also noticed my disc image wasnt .iso

Comment: The comments  are mainly our channel to ask for clarification. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1433631/edit) and add all the new information in the question. Please clarify what you mean by "disk image wasn't ISO". Did you download the image from the official Ubuntu site? If not do that.

Comment: Please also specify what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you're talking about; ie. do you mean Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop? a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS etc as many 22.04 options exist, and details of what you meant by "*disk image wasn't ISO*" as already asked.  As noted, details belong in the question (comment(s) will be erased once question provides the details asked for )

Comment: Please read the info on this site and start over again. If it was not an ISO who knows what you have done. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)